# Continuous map on a compact metric space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Im reading a chapter of compactness in Real Analysis, Carothers, 1ed. Actually, I cannot understand a proof for uniformly continuity captured below:
[image]
[image]

I cannot figure out a reason for the "Why?" above. Besides, Im a little confusing about finding inf of $δ_x$ and "reduce to finitely many $δ_x$". I mean why we need to get inf of $δ_x$?(In my opinion, since f is continuous, inf of $δ_x$ cannot guarantee the ρ(f(x),f(y)) that should be less than ε for arbitary x belonging to M. In other word, to prove f is uniformly continuous, we need to find a $δ_x$ that do not rely on x such that for ρ(f(x),f(y)) < ε for given ε>0. And so this $δ_x$ should be settle down at max of $δ_x$ instead of min.)

Comment: I on the other hand, don't understand the second part of your question. Could you explain it a little further?

Comment: Suppose $\inf_x \delta_x = D > 0$.  Now use $D$ in the definition of uniform continuity.

Comment: @AdamSaltz Now what?

Comment: Continuing with Adam's comment: then for any $\;\epsilon>0\;$ we have that $\;\rho(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon\;$ whenever $\;\rho(x,y)<D\;$ , which is the definition of unif. cont.

Comment: @tomasz: I've reedit it and please check it again^_^

Comment: Your last sentence shows the conceptual problem you're having. In all such arguments, inf is what is required. For example, if you consider $f(x)=x^2$ on $[0,1]$, then it's the $\delta$ required at $1$ that dictates all. I recommend you draw some pictures to understand this.

Comment: @TedShifrin: Take ur f(x)=$x^2$ (x belongs to [0,1]) as an example. By calculation, I get $δ_x$ equals to $\sqrt ε$, $\sqrt( 0.09 + ε)$, 0.8-$\sqrt(0.64-ε)$, 1-$\sqrt(1-ε)$ for x = 0, 0.3, 0.8, 1, respectively. So this $δ_x$ should be at least settle down at the max value of {$\sqrt ε$, $\sqrt( 0.09 + ε)$, 0.8-$\sqrt(0.64-ε)$, 1-$\sqrt(1-ε)$} for given ε("given ε" means ε has been preliminarily fixed) in order to preserve uniformly continuity, is that right?

Comment: No, if you need a $\delta$ that works for the several $x$ on your list, you need the *smallest* on your list!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to Why? is:

Then we can take

$inf\{\delta_x\}=s$,

and this $s$ is such that for any $x$, and $\epsilon>0$,  $d(x-y)<s$ implies $d(f(x)-f(y))<\epsilon$. So $f$ is uniformly continuous. This is just the definition of uniform continuity.

Choosing max of such $\delta$'s, even if/ when possible, would not give you the required result ( try!).

Comment: Take ur f(x)=$x^2$ (x belongs to [0,1]) as an example. By calculation, I get $δ_x$ equals to $\sqrt ε$, $\sqrt( 0.09 + ε)$, 0.8-$\sqrt(0.64-ε)$, 1-$\sqrt(1-ε)$ for x = 0, 0.3, 0.8, 1, respectively. So this $δ_x$ should be at least settle down at the max value of {$\sqrt ε$, $\sqrt( 0.09 + ε)$, 0.8-$\sqrt(0.64-ε)$, 1-$\sqrt(1-ε)$} for given ε("given ε" means ε has been preliminarily fixed) in order to preserve uniformly continuity, is that right?

Comment: I am not sure what you are aiming for. One of the

Comment: im so sorry cos i've used an example above and with it, I try to show that s should be equal to max($δ_x$}. Can you help me find out the error in it?